# Erro ao criar tabela com INDEX VISIBLE no Workbench

Tags: mysql, índices

Criei um diagrama de um BD utilizando o MySQL WorkBench e mandei gerar o script do mesmo. Mas acontece o seguinte erro quando vou executar a consulta:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  INDEX `fk_carro_leilao1_idx` (`leilao_idleilao` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `f' at line 15
```

Código SQL:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `carrosleilao`.`carro`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carrosleilao`.`carro` (
      `idcarro` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `modelo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `marca` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `ano` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
      `combustivel` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `precoFIPE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `referencia` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `preco_idpreco` INT NOT NULL,
      `leilao_idleilao` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idcarro`, `preco_idpreco`, `leilao_idleilao`),
      INDEX `fk_carro_preco_idx` (`preco_idpreco` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `fk_carro_leilao1_idx` (`leilao_idleilao` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_carro_preco`
        FOREIGN KEY (`preco_idpreco`)
        REFERENCES `carrosleilao`.`preco` (`idpreco`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_carro_leilao1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`leilao_idleilao`)
        REFERENCES `carrosleilao`.`leilao` (`idleilao`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Não consegui identificar o problema pois o script foi gerado pela própria ferramenta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Observando a parte "próxima do erro de sintaxe", arrisco dizer que você está utilizando o MySQL versão anterior à 8.0. Talvez a versão 5.7 que é a mais comum.

Veja as opções de índice disponíveis conforme a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html#create-index-options):

```
index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
  | COMMENT 'string'
```

Isso quer dizer que **não tem a opção de visibilidade do índice**:

```
  INDEX `fk_carro_preco_idx` (`preco_idpreco` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_carro_leilao1_idx` (`leilao_idleilao` ASC) VISIBLE,
```

Simplesmente remova a opção `VISIBLE` da consulta que vai prosseguir normalmente.

> Leitura recomendada: [**MySQL 8.0** Reference Manual - 8.3.12 Invisible Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html)

---

**BÔNUS:**

> "*- o script foi gerado pela própria ferramenta*"

Acontece que o Workbench, por padrão, vem configurado para modelagem na versão 8.0 do MySQL.

Para alterar, acesse as preferências relacionadas a modelagem do MySQL:

> Edit > Preferences > Modeling > MySQL.

Altere a opção **Default Target MySQL Version** para `5.7` (**ou a versão do seu servidor MySQL**).

Answer (score 1):

Tive esse problema algumas vezes. No caso estava usando MariaDB invés do MySQL. O Workbench já vem configurado para ser usado com MySQL 8.x. A opção VISIBLE não é reconhecida pelo MariaDB ou MySQL anterior ao 8.x. Vá em:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> Modeling -> MySQL
```

E em:

```
Model:
   Default Target MySQL Version:
```

coloque **5.7.35**
Que foi a última versão da família 5.7.x do MySQL antes da 8.x e até agora está funcionando com as últimas versões do MariaDB.